# Laravel unknown database error during migration

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I cannot run a Laravel migration inside a Homestead/Vagrant box. There are more questions like this, but none seem to have answers suitable for me.

I setup a blog website, its path inside the VirtualBox is `/home/vagrant/code/blog`. Then I created an empty file representing the SQLite database at `/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite`, as per instruction in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database). Furthermore, I edited the `/home/vagrant/code/blog/.env` file to contain the "correct" database information:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then I created a migration using `php artisan make:migration create_users_table` as is explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#running-migrations). But when I try to apply this migration using `php artisan migrate,` I get the following error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/blog$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database '/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = /home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /home/vagrant/code/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database '/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite'")
      /home/vagrant/code/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite", "homestead", "secret", [])
      /home/vagrant/code/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

So it says it cannot find the database even though I entered the absolute path to it, how is this possible? I know the path must be correct because when I run `ls /home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite` it is listed as an existing file..

How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to change your DB_CONNECTION variable from mysql to SQLite

Comment: According Giacomo said, you should change your environment file. If you read the Exception message your app is trying to connect to a database in MySQL called "/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite"

Comment: But that results in the error `InvalidArgumentException  : Database [SQLite] not configured.`

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

With this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=SQLite
```

in your .env file

Comment: This results in the error `InvalidArgumentException  : Database [SQlite] not configured.`

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the DB_DATABASE from your .env file and use the default in config/database.php which is

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

Comment: Then I get the error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'database.sqlite'`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your default database driver, which is currently set with `mysql` i.e. `DB_CONNECTION=SQLite`. Please replace it with `DB_CONNECTION=SQLite`. And also confirm the `database.sqlite` file exists on path `/home/vagrant/code/blog/database/database.sqlite`

Comment: If I make that change I get the error `InvalidArgumentException  : Database [SQLite] not configured.` Furthermore, as said in the question, I confirmed the existence of the database.sqlite file by using `ls`, which shows it is at that precise location.

Comment: Please try `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` instead. And also clear cache with `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

U are likely to be running two instances of mysql on you pc, that was my case, use the terminal to create a database and the details you use there should be the ones you should use.